# Java jbutton msg box conflict

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have two jbutton in a jpanel and when you click the first button you see a msg box saying "good morning" and when you click the second you see a "good night" msg box . But when i click on the first button and not closing the msg box first i can not click the second button to see the message.

Can anyone help me?

thanks.

Comment: Post some code first.

Comment: I suppose that you are using modal dialog to show the message. If that so, you must to close dialog first, and after that you can perform any action on your UI. If you post code, we will see what you want to acomplish. Could you post your code, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would suggest two basic things, you are using either a `JOptionPane` or modal `JDialog` to display your messages.

In either case, a modal dialog blocks the parent window until it is dismissed.  You need to make the dialog modeless instead.

Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)